# Problem /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option -* running code in python3

Tags: python-3.x

[Error image and editor configured in UTF8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJWLl.png)
I am trying to run the following code in python 3.7.5

```
pi = 3.14159
radius = 15.3
print ('Circle Area is', pi * radius ** 2)
```

does not run error appears: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\ xc3' in file

adding the command line `#! - * - conding: utf8 - * -` the following error appears:

```
/ bin / sh: 0: Illegal option - *
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be without spaces and also its not `conding` its `coding`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

not

```
 #! - * - conding: utf8 - * -
```

Comment: I made this change and the error is now ('Circle \ xc3 \ x81rea \ xc3 \ xa9 of', 735.4148031000001)

Comment: I added an image, a look is apparently configured

Comment: try to check your terminal if its utf-8 

`import sys print(sys.stdout.encoding)`

Comment: `c381` and `c3a9` are utf-8 for codepoint 00c1 and 00e9 which is A-acute and e-acute.

Comment: vs code code runner might be the problem, please try to run in regular terminal. and also run the code that i added in my last command

Comment: try to follow this: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/365

Comment: I checked and the terminal is set to UTF-8

Comment: in the terminal the code works, I think it's the same code runner

Comment: in fact this by default it dosent use the same terminal, so that is the workaround you can do to fix the problem in code runner.  you could use below setting (File->Preference->Settings) to run code in Integrated Terminal:

{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line with Python 3. The default encoding is UTF-8 with Python 3+.

Comment: my VSCode editor is configured with UTF-8 with python3, still errors persist if I don't add this line the code doesn't execute